# Need to read a file and assign its content to a function

Tags: fortran, fortran90

I am a novice to Fortran 90 and stack overflow, and I have a simple question (I think).
I have a file, named Eq1, containing the following Fortran mathematical expression:

x**2

The objective is to input this expression from the file, and use it in a function inside fortran. I have tried the following

```
REAL FUNCTION  f(x)
    IMPLICIT  NONE
    REAL (kind =8), INTENT(IN) :: x

    open(1,file = 'Eq1',status='old')
        read(1,*) f
    close(1)
END FUNCTION  f
```

and when I do

```
print *, f(0.1d+0)
```

inside the main program, I get the following error message:

```
Fortran runtime error: Bad real number in item 1 of list input
```

Thanks for the help!
Cheers

Comment: Well, I can tell you where that error is coming from - your function is defined as a REAL function (which means that `f` is a REAL), but you are trying to read characters into it.  To get your text from the file you need to define a character string and read into that.

Comment: That being said, I think what you are trying to do is not at all trivial and I'll leave it to other folks to say whether or not it's even possible

Comment: What you have is not a simple question.  You seem to want to parse a string and extract a function from it.  You can certainly do this in Fortran but you're going to have to work a lot harder.  Like most compiled languages Fortran won't turn strings into code for you.

Comment: This is a pretty difficult task for a novice. Languages that contain ‛eval() ‛ are better suited for these operations.

Answer (score 3):

Fortran does not have a string evaluation functionality as some script languages, e.g. Python's [eval()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#eval).

You have to write your own string to expression parser, which is not a trivial task.

One simple workaround is to call Python's [eval()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#eval) with [SYSTEM](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/SYSTEM.html) and use it's output:

```
REAL FUNCTION  f(x)
    IMPLICIT  NONE
    REAL (kind =8), INTENT(IN) :: x
    CHARACTER(LEN=200) EXP
    CHARACTER(LEN=400) CMD
    open(1,file = 'Eq1',status='old')
        read(1,*) exp
    close(1)
    WRITE(CMD, "(A,f14.7, A, A, A)") 'python -c "x=',x,';print ',trim(exp), '" > out.txt'
    CALL system(CMD)
    open(2,file = 'out.txt',status='old')
        read(2,*) f
    close(2)
END FUNCTION  f

program calc
  implicit none
  real f
  print *, f(0.1d+0)      
  print *, f(2.0d+0)
  print *, f(3.0d+0)
  print *, f(4.0d+0)
end program calc
```

Output:

```
9.9999998E-03
4.000000
9.000000
16.00000
```